# Stepping into the break point when using Win32 thru a CLI Wrapper in a C# .NET Application

Tags: mixed-mode, visual-c++-2012

I have the following solution structure:
Project Files

```
1. Win32 C++ DLL
2. CLI/C++ Wrapper DLL
3. WinForm C# Exe
4. MFC Tester Exe
```

When I access the Win32 using the following stucture:

```
WinForm => CLI Wrapper => Win32 DLL
```

I can debug the WinForm and the CLI Wrapper but not the Win32 DLL.
I can only unit test the Win32 DLL thru an MFC Tester.
Is there a way to seamlessly debug until the Win32 DLL if it is run from the WinForm GUI not the MFC GUI?

I tried the following:

```
1. Attach WinForm Running and break thru the Win32 DLL
2. Checked the setup of the visual studio project
    Using the following answer on the following previous stackoverflow question's accepted answer. (e.g. setting to Mixed debug, setting /Ci option, etc)
```

[No Symbols loaded in mixed C# C(win32) project using VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535075/no-symbols-loaded-in-mixed-c-sharp-cwin32-project-using-vs2010)

Do you have other ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: Did you select 'Native debugging' in the debug options?

Comment: @leppie it works. This should be the answer but it is just a comment. Write this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you select 'Native debugging' in the debug options of the project. It will work then if you native code has symbols/PDB's.