# Can't use/debug unmanaged DLL from C#

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, mixed-mode

I have a C# application and a C++ DLL, both x86. The Application is the startup project, the DLL project is inside the same solution and is referenced as a project. The C++ DLL outputs its PDB file with the same name as the DLL inside the Debug folder of the Application.

I have a function called `SomeFunction` that I'm trying to execute in C#. When the code reaches that line, it stops there. The UI of the C# application continues to be responsive, but the breakpoint never leaves that line (and that's in Form_Load).

If I try to set the DLL as startup project and tell it to execute the C# application, then C# will crash at that line with: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'SomeFunction' in DLL 'SomeDLL.dll'.

This is the declaration of the function that I'm trying to call:

```
[DllImport("SomeDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "SomeFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int SomeFunction(IntPtr hwnd);
```

This is the function's declaration from the C++ header:

```
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
MYDLL_API extern int SomeFunction(HWND hWnd);
```

This is how I call it from C#:

```
var someAnswer = SomeFunction(_hwnd);
```

**UPDATE**: since the discussion below could take some time to read, here's the answer in the nutshell: I was missing an extern "C". Also, in order to debug the DLL (which was also a problem), the project needs to support native debugging both from C++ and C#, here's an excellent list that I went through and at the end it was all good!

[No Symbols loaded in mixed C# C(win32) project using VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535075/no-symbols-loaded-in-mixed-c-sharp-cwin32-project-using-vs2010)

Comment: Have you tried to call that `SomeFunction` while debugging? (.net could load c++ dll dynamically)

Comment: Add ::DebugBreak() to the dll.  This will cause a break into the debugger and allow you to set breakpoints. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run code that calls `SomeFunction` to ensure unmanaged .dll is loaded
2. Go into Debug -> Windows -> Modules and check the .dll path and `symbols` status. You can try to load `symbols` in context menu of your c++ dll in that window.

(very often happens that .net loads different (not expected) version of unmanaged .dll)

Now I'm pretty sure that the problem is that your exported function name is mangled.
Try to define function like this:

```
extern "C" MYDLL_API int PASCAL SomeFunction(HWND hWnd);
```

In C#:

```
[DllImport("SomeDLL.dll")]
public static extern int SomeFunction(IntPtr hwnd);
```

Comment: I'm trying to call the function. The breakpoint never advances from that line in C#. Actually, the DLL doesn't even show up in modules, which indicates that it's not even loaded? I don't see why this happens. It should crash when the function is called. The DLL is there in the folder, why isn't it loading it?!

Comment: .dll will be loaded only at first call. .net calls LoadModule and so on. What is the message of the crash? You can also setup brek point in `Main` dll function. So it will be able to stop before actual .dll function call. Also look at the `Output` window before crash and send us.

Comment: Don't forget that .exe and .dll must be in the **same** folder and all .dll dependencies must be accessible.

Comment: The DLL uses some Win32 API from kernel and so on, but I suppose I don't have to copy those over in the same folder do I? Otherwise, yes, they're in the same folder, yet now, when trying to start the C# from the DLL, with the DLL as startup project, I get: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'SomeFunction' in DLL 'SomeDLL.dll'. I just don't see why this happens...

Comment: Maybe you forgot about the name mangling? Is there really `SomeFunction` exported? (You can check with `DependencyWalker` or add `extern "C"` before the function declaration)

Comment: I'm looking with Total Commander and that's indeed the name of the function that is exported. Same in the .lib file. I tried adding "extern" and the same thing happens :(.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120359/discussion-between-dmitriy-zapevalov-and-axonn).

Comment: It was because of the missing extern "C" :). Thank you again! Oh, and remember that CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl? It is indeed necessary. It is required because I'm passing IntPtr as a hwnd. Without that, it crashes during debug with "A call has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. "

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem that it won't set the breakpoint beforehand is that the DLL is loaded on demand via p-invoke. If VS doesn't think the DLL is a dependency, it may not allow you to set the breakpoint beforehand.

You could add a [DebugBreak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx) to your c++ code. Then simply run your app, don't debug it. Then when it executes this statement, you will get a **Just in time debugging** alert allowing you to jump into the c++ debugger.

### C++ as startup

Alternatively, you could make the DLL the startup project, but change the debug settings so that it launches an external process - in this case your app .exe.

This time however, you don't need the DebugBreak(), just a regular breakpoint.

Now when you debug, your DLLs symbols are loaded thus allowing the break points to work.

I used this trick a lot with ActiveX/COM.

Comment: I tried the DebugBreak thingy directly in DLL Main. BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {DebugBreak();}. Nothing happens. As I replied below to Dmitriy, it seems like the DLL is somehow inaccessible... don't understand yet how or why. Will now try what you suggested.

Comment: I'm doing something very wrong... somewhere. I just don't know where. I tried what you said and now I do manage to get a breakpoint in DllMain, even without the DebugBreak. It works. However, when the C# is about to call the function, it breaks with: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'SomeFunction' in DLL 'SomeDLL.dll'..

Comment: There's something worse at foot here... I can't even access the DLL from C#. I'll get to the bottom of this and update the question accordingly.

Comment: No worries. maybe check the p-invoke signature. You could also verify the c++ function is being exported right by viewing the DLL in Dependency Viewer. Good luck